# Anchor href linking to tab without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor

I am using the below code to be able to switch between tabs. But i am not able to link to tab using `<a href="#tab5">Go to tab5</a>` This is not working.
I want to make it work using my current code.

What do I have to add on jQuery document .ready?

I am searching for 2 days now and i can't find any suitable solution.Thanks in advance

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();



        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });





});
```

Comment: can you provide your html codes also

Comment: Without your specific HTML this is difficult to answer. You have wasted 2 days so far. Don't waste any more. *Post more details*. It should be trivial to fix :)